# SAPUI5: How to fire an event when the element shows the data from Odata?

Tags: sapui5

I want to fire an event as soon as an element completely shows the bound data from an odata service.

Which event is suitable for that?

Please note it may happen that odata is loaded while it takes some second to show the data inside of the element.

```
var oObjectListItem = new sap.m.ObjectListItem();
                var aItems = [
                    "title",
                    "number",
                    "numberUnit",
                    "intro",
                    "icon",
                    "activeIcon",
                    "iconDensityAware",
                    "markFavorite",
                    "markFlagged",
                    "showMarkers",
                    "numberState",
                    "titleTextDirection",
                    "introTextDirection",
                    "numberTextDirection",
                    "markLocked",
                    "type",
                    "visible",
                    "unread",
                    "selected",
                    "counter"
                ];
                for (var k = 0; k < aItems.length; k++) {
                    if (typeof this._aTabs[i].oTabHeaderBindingInfos[aItems[k]] === "object" && this._aTabs[i].oTabHeaderBindingInfos[aItems[k]]) {
                        oObjectListItem.bindProperty(aItems[k], this._aTabs[i].oTabHeaderBindingInfos[aItems[k]]);
                    } else if (this._aTabs[i].oTabHeaderBindingInfos[aItems[k]]) {
                        oObjectListItem.setProperty(aItems[k], this._aTabs[i].oTabHeaderBindingInfos[aItems[k]]);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Can you try with attachDataReceived event of binding ?  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Binding.html#attachDataReceived

Comment: I want to use ObjectListItem (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ObjectListItem.html) and it does not have that event.

Comment: attachDataReceived event will be applied to your binding. Meaning if you are using a List, you will need to do: lis.getBinding('items').attachDataReceived(function(e) { //do something});

Comment: It will be helpful if you can paste your code so we can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj I added some parts of my code. I don't use the list. It is a single element that its number and title is bounded. Actually the first part  of the `if` is run.

Comment: @RahulBhardwaj Also `oObjectListItem.getBinding("title")` returns undefined

Comment: Because its a property not aggregation. Curious, why cant you execute your code just after for loop ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142577/discussion-between-martin-and-rahul-bhardwaj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dicussed over the chat:
We will write our own onAfterRendering method:

```
oControl.addEventDelegate({ 
   "onAfterRendering": function(){ 
     console.log('called'); 
     // Custom Logic
  } 
})
```

oControl is your ObjectListItem.

**NOTE**: It will called twice. First time without data and second time when bindng is complete

let me know if this works